# Swift singleton not accessible from within function

Tags: ios, swift3, singleton

I'm trying to access a singleton value that is accessible throughout my application apart from one function. I can get the value at either end of the function however inside the function it can't be accessed. To confirm I have set these values so they are not empty.

My singleton is declared as follows:

```
var customer: Customer = Customer.sharedInstance

final class Customer {

    static let sharedInstance = Customer()

    var name: String!
    var address: String!
    var zipcode: String!
    var id: String!

    private init() {}

}
```

I can access any of these values from within viewDidLoad and other methods apart from one which is below:

```
fileprivate func processCustomer() {
... Do logic here
print(customer.name) // Print's out nil
... perform closure method
... print(customer.name) // Print's nil
}
```

Any ideas as I've rewritten it twice already. I've also removed fileprivate and renaming the function. It's almost as if the function can't read the value of a singleton more than once??

Thanks

Comment: Remove your global `var customer ...` and always access the singlets using `Customer.sharedInstance`

Comment: This way should work as I have a similar singleton which i can access from multiple locations,

Comment: Where do you set `name`?

Comment: In another controller